# Xhr uploading event.loaded issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, upload

```
opts.xhr=function(){
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

    // Upload progress
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = e.loaded / e.total * 100;
            console.log('Progress info:', e.loaded, e.total, Math.round(percentComplete),  Math.round(e.loaded/1024/1024), Math.round(e.total/1024/1024));
        }
    }
    return xhr;
}
return $.ajax(opts);
```

Progress info: 53657600 2666153229 2 51 2543

Progress info: 55656448 2666153229 2 53 2543

Progress info: 57655296 2666153229 2 55 2543

Progress info: 59850752 2666153229 2 57 2543

Progress info: **4489216** 2666153229 **0** 4 2543

Progress info: **4800512** 2666153229 **0** 5 2543

**WTF?!**

Why it's jumping back? Shows 59850752 is loaded and then 4489216. O_o
What i'm doing wrong?

Request URL:http://mydomain.com/admin/upload?callback=jQuery18307878572104964405_1372440424301

Request Headers

```
Accept:text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryVHTBFWPenOcByyrT
Origin:http://mydomain.com
Referer:http://mydomain.com/admin/add
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Query String Parameters

```
callback:jQuery18307878572104964405_1372440424301
```

Request Payload

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryVHTBFWPenOcByyrT
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images[]"; filename="smerch_BDRip-AVC.mkv"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryVHTBFWPenOcByyrT--
```

Comment: Perhaps some more information about your situation would be helpful.

Comment: What info you need? Haven't i posted all i got? O_o

Comment: Which browser?  Which OS?  Does this happen with ALL files, or one specific file?  Does the request ultimately succeed?  etc, etc.

Comment: Updated the question. Request is dropped due to timeout, after 2 mins. I'll try different files.

Comment: Does this happen with all files/request, or just some?  Is this really a 2.7 GB request?  Have you tried reproducing on other browsers?

Comment: That's odd that this request is timing out.  It shouldn't as long as data is flowing.

Comment: With small files all is ok.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I figured out that the problem is that your backend drops connection without the response and Axios tries to re-upload data (and sometimes throws "Network Error").

The solution is to check your proxy/firewall config between the client and backend server and extend timeouts and allowed body size

e.g. for nginx

```
client_max_body_size 3G
```