# Jquery - Upload progress bar using XHR: event.loaded resets after a while

Tags: jquery, file-upload, progress-bar

Using jsf 2.2.7 and jquery 1.9.1

I've made a progress bar using XMLHttpRequest.upload that works pretty well, except that, as stated in the title, the event.loaded resets after a while in certain situations, causing the progress to go back to 0%. I can't even say it's exclusively due to the file's size, because it happens:

a) when uploading 2gb+ files locally
b) when uploading 1gb+ files through LAN
c) when uploading 15**mb**+ files in the published site (which was when I first experienced the problem)

Both (b) and (c) reset more often than (a) and never reach 100%. I can see in the browser that the upload keeps going on correctly, but the bar doesn't reflect that progress, since it loses track all the time.

Can anyone tell me what's going on? The only similar problem I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370382/xhr-uploading-event-loaded-issue), but it wasn't solved.

### Code:

```
var media;

$(document).on("change", "#mediaFile", function() {
    media = this.files[0];
    //some display code
});


$(document).on("click", "#submit", function() {
    if (typeof media != 'undefined') {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (xhr.upload) {
            var progress;
            xhr.upload.onloadstart = function() {
                //some display
            }
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    //this e.loaded resets after a while
                    progress = Math.floor(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
                    $("#upload_bg").css("width", progress + '%');
                    $("#upload_percent").text(progress + '%');
                    console.log("loaded: " + e.loaded + " / total: " + e.total + " / percentage: " + Math.floor(e.loaded / e.total * 100) + "%");
                }
            }
            xhr.upload.onloadend = function() {
                //some display code
            }
        }
        xhr.open('post', URL, true);
        xhr.send(media);
    }
});
```

---

### Log for a local 2.1gb file:

loaded: 1196032 / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 0%
loaded: 22118400 / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 1%
loaded: 32849920 / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 1%
*(...)*
loaded: 1559707648 / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 73%
loaded: 1572290560 / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 74%
**loaded: 163840** / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 0%  <------ resets
loaded: 17924096 / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 0%
loaded: 28803072 / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 1%
*(...)*
loaded: 1761443840 / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 83%
**loaded: 1638400** / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 0%  <------ resets
loaded: 16809984 / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 0%
loaded: 42942464 / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 2%
*(...)*
loaded: 2075492352 / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 98%
loaded: 2099511296 / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 99%
loaded: 2109656694 / total: 2109656694 / percentage: 100%

---

### Log for a 1.3gb file sent via LAN:

loaded: 131072 / total: 1308543464 / percentage: 0%
loaded: 4014080 / total: 1308543464 / percentage: 0%
loaded: 15826944 / total: 1308543464 / percentage: 1%
loaded: 21741568 / total: 1308543464 / percentage: 1%
*(...)*
loaded: 181764096 / total: 1308543464 / percentage: 13%
**loaded: 131072** / total: 1308543464 / percentage: 0%   <------ resets
loaded: 11993088 / total: 1308543464 / percentage: 0%
loaded: 17874944 / total: 1308543464 / percentage: 1%
*(...)*
loaded: 76972032 / total: 1308543464 / percentage: 5%
loaded: 82853888 / total: 1308543464 / percentage: 6%
loaded: 177487872 / total: 1308543464 / percentage: 13%
**loaded: 32768** / total: 1308543464 / percentage: 0%  <------ resets
***(never reaches 100%)***